# Android Fatal Error

Tags: android

Back to the same error...

`01-13 02:46:05.971: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 02:46:05.971: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2922): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.s.android.test/com.s.android.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.s.android.test.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.s.android.test-1.apk]`

I have imported a package to this application..do I have to add those activities to  my Manifest file?
Please answer..
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which class did you call?

how about post your AndroidManifest.xml?

It should be the problem of your "intent" class.

When you want to intent a class, you should register it in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there may be an invalid class type in AndroidManifest.xml. Really some more information would make this easier to help you figure out.

Comment: yep..I forgot to add the class to the Manifest file..thanks for your post Graham

Answer (score 0):

whenever you find any fatal exception, check your manifest file.

I am unable to get your exact point of view but,
I think in your case,
you have to enter your new activity name (or package) in manifest file if you use intent.

It would be nice if you post your manifest file code. :)